# What does the syntax of this excel function X^{A,B,C} do

Tags: excel

I tried `=4^{2,3,4}` and it returns 16

So I guess it's raising 4 to the power of the first number in the array..  When would it use the other numbers (3,4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula returns an array. If you want to see the results in cells, select 3 cells in a row, enter the formula in the first one, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

The formula you used returns an array of results.

If you press <kbd>F2</kbd> on the cell containing the formula and press <kbd>F9</kbd>, you should see `={16,64,256}`.

Comment: Also, as Hong Ooi pointed out (very correctly), you can evaluate them by selecting 3 cells in a row and using Ctrl+Shift+Enter. If the array was `{2;3;4}` instead, you would get them by selecting 3 cells in a column and using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.